# Cannot save RadioGroup's selected Item in sharedPreferences - Fragment

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have `fragment` and inside fragment, i want to store selected choice of RadioGroup (Male/Female) in `SharedPreferences`.
Following code i have tried, it works if i use it in `Activity`, but its not working in `Fragment`.

while loading and inserting int value of selected choice, it returns correct value - Male = 0, Female = 1, but during loading data, it crashes with 
`NullPointerException` on following statement

```
 if (i >= 0) 
         ((RadioButton) ((RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.genderSelect)).getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);
```

I have tried searching lots of solution on stackoverflow, but no luck.
any suggestion or help on this? Thank you.

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment,container,false);

    //Initializing views
    saveButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    cancelButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

    userGender = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.genderSelect);

    loadProfileFields();
   return rootView;
   }


 private void saveProfile() {

    savedFileData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedFileData.edit();
 RadioGroup localRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.genderSelect);
    editor.putInt(preference_key_profile_gender,
             localRadioGroup.indexOfChild(getActivity().findViewById(localRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
  editor.apply();
 }


 private void loadProfileFields() {

    SharedPreferences loadProfile = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(loadProfile != null){

        int i = loadProfile.getInt(preference_key_profile_gender, -1);
       // i gives me the right value, but it throws NullPointerExc inside If statement
        if( i >= 0){

                ((RadioButton) ((RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.genderSelect)).getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "RadioGroup" - in the fragment or in Activity ?

Comment: inside fragment's layout. @ShadabAnsari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `findViewById()` everytime you want to use a view.
Change your methods -

```
private void saveProfile() {

    savedFileData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedFileData.edit();

    editor.putInt(preference_key_profile_gender,
             userGender.indexOfChild(userGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
  editor.apply();
 }


 private void loadProfileFields() {

    SharedPreferences loadProfile = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(loadProfile != null){

        int i = loadProfile.getInt(preference_key_profile_gender, -1);
       // i gives me the right value, but it throws NullPointerExc inside If statement
        if( i >= 0){

                ((RadioButton)userGender.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: when you use `RadioGroup`'s instance userGender, it won't give me method `setChecked()` because it can be only executed on `RadioButton`. I have tried your code by the way.

Comment: Use this -  (userGender.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was making new instance of `RadioGroup` everytime, which was the problem. solved.